# Solved: How to change Solidity linter [solc] compiler version in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: solidity, compiler, visual-studio-code

[image]
Hi may I know how to change my Solidity linter compiler version in Visual Studio Code(vscode)? OR Visual studio code how to specify solidity compiler version?

The only Solidity related extensions I have installed are solidity 0.0.38 by Juan Blanco, and Solidity Extended 3.0.2 by beaugunderson.

I have applied the User Settings in VS Code as the following but still get error:

```
{"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "files.associations": {
    "*.sol": "solidity"
  },
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "material-icon-theme.showUpdateMessage": false,

  "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion" : "latest",
  "solidity.linter":"solium",
  "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": "contracts",
  "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "node_modules",
  "solidity.soliumRules": {
    "imports-on-top": 0,
    "variable-declarations": 0,
    "no-inline-assembly": 5,
    "indentation": ["error",2],
    "quotes": ["error","double"]
  },
  "solidity.validationDelay": 1000,

  if in Windows system:
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows":"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
  "window.zoomLevel":1
```

Now I've also install Solidity globally in my Linux: $ sudo npm install -g solc
Then I've got this from the terminal:
/home/userXYZ/.npm-global/bin/solcjs -> /home/userXYZ/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/solc/solcjs
+ solc@0.4.22

Then changed User Setting: "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion" : "latest"

Then re-started VS Code, still I am getting this error...
Please help. Thank you

Comment: This is not off-topic!!! It is about upgrading a plugin to use the most recent version of the solidity compiler. It surely will help others solidity developers trying to do the same thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still have a problem with the version in VS Code, this worked for me:

Install specific `solc` version locally or globally: `npm i -g solc` or `npm i solc`.

Add this setting in local VSCode settings: `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.7.4+commit.3f05b770",
    "solidity.enableLocalNodeCompiler": false
}
```

In my case I am using `solidity v0.7.4`. Note also the other config: `"solidity.enableLocalNodeCompiler": false`

Comment: How do you find what commit it should be? I.e. how did you know you needed +commit.3f05b770

Comment: @thatguyintech I don't remember, but I think there is a list here will all the details: https://etherscan.io/solcversions

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your using VS code and have the official solidity extension maintained by Juan Blanco (found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity)). The extension is official in the sense that it is the only extension recommended by [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/ides/).

The extension provides a very easy way of toggling compilers:

1. In any *.sol file, right click and press "change workspace compiler version (Remote)".
2. Choose your compiler.

Thats it.

[image]

Comment: This answer works perfectly. Also remember each workspace can have different compiler versions.

Answer (score 6):

[Solved] Thank you Juan Blanco for his advice. So the main issue is that the forked extension(Solidity Extended by beaugunderson) was highjacking this one(solidity by Juan Blanco) hence I had the old version of the compiler 0.4.17 but not the latest version 0.4.23.

Set it by opening your VS Code setting at /home/userXYZ/.config/Code/User/settings.json in Linux, then change the compiler version like below

"solidity.compileUsingLocalVersion": "null",

"solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion" : "v0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e",

Comment: How did you change the version? I removed other extensions and it does not work

Comment: by installing solc in your system

Answer (score 4):

Go to node_modules -> solc -> package.json -> version of your compiler can be found at the bottom.

**Never edit the package.json file**

**To fix the problem**

-Copy the version number at the bottom 
**ex:-**"version": "0.5.1"

-go to your contract and paste on pragma.
  **ex:-** pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

This should fix your issue.

Comment: I don't have Go to node_modules on the VSC

Answer (score 3):

I tried sooooooooo many things to fix this in Nov 2021 and this is finally what did it for me....btw, many thanks to Russo for his insight about Blanco's extension vs Beaugunderson's!  While his quick fix didn't immediately fix, I was able to find the needle in the haystack, finally:

- Open VSCode
- On left side, open Extensions
  (Now here, check what Solidity extensions you installed!  I happened to have had BOTH Blanco's and Beaugunderson's extension installed - You only need Blanco's!  So make sure HIS is installed and if you have Beaugunderson's then uninstall it!  Should only have Blanco's..)
  Done.  This worked at least for me.  Hope it works for you.

Comment: I tried sooooo many things too and this resolved my issue completely!!

Comment: Omg dude ! I was so piss off by Visual studio and this fix all my problems ! Yeees !! I don't know how to thank you enough ^-^

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped me. In the file named .solhint.json, I replaced

```
{
  "extends": "solhint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "compiler-version": ["error", "^0.8.0"],
    "func-visibility": ["warn", { "ignoreConstructors": true }]
  }
}
```

with this

```
{
  "extends": "solhint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "compiler-version": "^0.6.0",
    "func-visibility": ["warn", { "ignoreConstructors": true }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to `npm install solc@specific-version-number`

This resolved the error for me

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this question was answered, but just in case others are using Hardhat, you can edit the hardhat.config.js with an entry for the Solidity compilers you want. If a version isn't installed, hardhat will install it for you. Here's an example:

```
solidity: {
    compilers: [
     
      {
        version: "0.6.0",
      }, 
      {
        version: "0.8.10",
      },
    ],
  },
```