# VSC highlighting problem with pragma, compiler version

Tags: solidity, solcjs

My Visual Studio Code is highlighting problem with `pragma` statement and I have no clue how to fix this.

Error is saying:

```
Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.Emscripten.clang 
- note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
```

I created new folder, I opened it in VSC, I created new file `Function.sol`, then I wrote some basic contract to start learning syntax and stuff:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract MyContract {

    function myFunction(uint id) public view returns (uint) {
        
        // ...
        // function body
        // ... 

    }
}
```

And in my VSC it looks like this:
[image]

I have similar errors with every `.sol` file, even in some forked projects.

I have installed globally `npm install -g solcjs`
And my solcjs version is: `0.8.10+commit.fc410830.Emscripten.clang`

How can I deal with that kind of problems?

---

[EDIT]

I followed steps from: [Solved: How to change Solidity linter [solc] compiler version in Visual Studio Code?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46158/solved-how-to-change-solidity-linter-solc-compiler-version-in-visual-studio-c)

Firstly I added those two commands to my `settings.json`, but using my current `solcjs` version  :

```json
{
    "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.8.10+commit.fc410830",
    "solidity.enableLocalNodeCompiler": false
}
```

And here the second command is disabled with: `Unknown Configuration Setting`
[image]

Problem with `pragma` is still highlighted.

Secondly I disabled the `Solidity Extended` extension by `beaugunderson`

And now `pragma` statement is no longer highlighted as an error.

But whenever I change the project and start working on some lower `pragma` than my specified in the `settings.json` problem comes back.

As far as I understand the statement:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0
```

Is saying: "Compile this file with compiler version not lower than 0.5.0
And I have to keep the compiler version exac same as in the pragma statement to avoid this highlighting error.

Is it how it supposed to be? Or is there any solution to that?

Comment: Please use just Juan Blanco solidity plugin it has a nice menu to easily fix the version issue.

Comment: I already uninstalled the other plugin, now I have only that one by Juan Blanco.
Can you please provide me some additional informations about this "menu"?

Comment: Follow the instructions from this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/99311/.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem.